# How to set drop down display none when any specific option selected using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using a asp.net screen to enter the data as we as I also want to use same screen as red-only mode to view only for some users. 
I have drop down in my screen that default selected index is 0 and text is 'Please Select' these drop downs are not mandatory so in edit mode user may not select any value for drop downs so default value would be 'Please Select' but when user open a same screen in read-only mode to view the saved data I want to hide those drop-down which are having default value as 'Please Select' but by using CSS. I have an option using jquery but I am looking a way by using css if it is possible. I have two css file that I am changing dynamically for read-only mode and edit mode.

I got some css as follows, in same way I am looking solution for my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>


        select [value=two][selected=selected] {
        display:none
        visibility:hidden;
        }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

         <th>Show This Drop down</th>
         <select id="ddlNumber">
           <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
           <option value="one">one</option>
           <option value="two" selected="selected">two</option>
           <option value="three">three</option>
           <option value="four">four</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <br>
         <th>Hide This Drop down by css</th>
         <select id="ddlAlpha">
           <option value="-1" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
           <option value="1">A</option>
           <option value="2">B</option>
           <option value="3">C</option>
           <option value="4">D</option>
         </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the read-only CSS all you need is select { display:none; }

Comment: @Gerard, it will hide all drop-downs in screen I want to hide only to those drop-downs which selected text is "Please Select"

Comment: You need to assign an ID to the select. Can you post the relevant HTML here?

Comment: @Gerard, I have update my post with sample HTML

Comment: If you mean to hide the `select` element based on which option is selected, that is not going to work with CSS, as the `option` element is a child of the `select`, it takes a parent selector to solve that, which is not available as of today.

Comment: @LGSon is right. You would need Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Gerard .. I will do it with JavaScript.